# How to pass arguments to a remote powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, terminal

I have a PowerShell script statically hosted on my website and I want to run it on my machine without manually downloading it. So I do this:

```sh
iwr https://mywebsite/test.ps1 | iex
```

Which works perfectly until you don't need to pass any arguments. But if I need to use arguments what options do I have?

As a workaround I can use variables instead of arguments like so:

```sh
$arg=$true; iwr https://mywebsite/test.ps1 | iex
```

but this is not ideal.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ScriptBlock from the script file and execute that:

```bsh
& ([scriptblock]::Create((iwr https://mywebsite/test.ps1))) -param1 123 -param2 "Hello there"
```